# How to edit the filters for the List Views? Seeing error "This list view can't be filtered". Any thoughts?

Tags: lightning-experience, list-view

Just seeing this weird issue when trying to edit the filters in the Accounts tab. I logged in as Sys admin, but still not able to succeed. Any thoughts, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check following possibilities

User Permissions Needed
[image]

- Some list views have predefined filter scopes and can’t be filtered.
  For example, the SOQL query for a generic Team list view or the
  Recently Viewed list view doesn’t allow further filtering of the
  query results.
- If you see Clone in the controls instead of Edit List Filters, you
  don’t have permission to edit this list view. Select Clone to clone a
  list view, save it under a different name, and select sharing
  settings. Then edit the filters for the cloned list view, if needed

Here some of the reference links:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews_edit_filters_lex.htm&type=5
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000p9kCQAQ

Comment: Thanks @Shilpa. I logged in as Sys admin, do you mean still I need user permission to edit the filters. Moreover, the List View is custom one. I can alter the filter values for the same List views in classic, but not in LEX. Is that a limitation or am I missing something?

Comment: are these list views deployed from any other org or package? or created in the same org only?

Comment: Hi Shilpa, it has been created few months ago in Salesforce classic and it is in the same org. Recently, we switched to LEX and getting hit with several constraints, restrictions and limitations.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason behind this, but I think it might be because of migrating the list view from classic to lightning experience. Few reference links: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l2aKQAQ
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231496&type=1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant share list views with groups in lightning experience.Either it has to be with you or all users.I think the list is shared with certain groups of users hence you are not able to edit it

These list view features aren’t available in Lightning Experience.

•  Inline editing of fields 
•   Following records directly from a list 
•   Sharing list views with groups 
•   Clone list views
•   Mass actions, custom actions, or custom buttons 
•   Advanced filter logic 
•   Drag-and-drop scheduling for account, contact, and lead list views 
•   Feeds 
•   The printer icon icon to create a printable view of a list

Refer to this link - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_gaps_limitations_data_access.htm